# Spring data jpa, externalizing native queries

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data jpa for executing native Query, here is the example.

```
@Query(value = "select name from customer", nativeQuery = true) 
public List<String> findNameNative() ;
```

Now, due to company constraint can't put the entire query here, but query is pretty huge, like 100 lines.

N we have many such queries.

Is there a way i can define queries in a separate file like xml or properties file and refer them here. (to keep the code clean)

Appericiate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After many efforts and tries found the solution.

1) create the xml file (with any name) in resources folder of your project. Say testSQL.xml inside resources /query

2) follow the xml standard of 'orm.xml' in testSQL.xml, this copy paste the header and create the tags of,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<named-native-query>
</named-native-query>
</entity-mapping>
```

3) in this xml create the tag with named-native-query tag.

```
<named-native-query name="XyzEntity.methodName">
<query>
<! [CDATA[
Your native query
] ] >
</query>
</named-native-query>
```

Note - > multiple such native named query tags can be added and all of them must reside between

```
<entity-mapping> </entity-mapping>
```

4) "XyzEntity" mentioned in name tag in above step, should have a Jpa repository and in that repository we should have method with the same name as the tag. I. E.

```
public interface XyzRepo extends JpaRepository <XyzEntity, Long> {
Tuple methodName() ;
```

}

5) add the testSQL.xml in application property file as below

```
spring.jpa.mapping-resources = query/testSQL.xml
```

N then you can call this method normal spring way.

Kindly let me know if someone is stuck on this and need detail solution.

Comment: If I wanted to use properties file then this "spring.jpa.mapping-resources = appQueries.properties"  will work ? . I wanted to go with properties file.

Comment: Whar if I want to pass parameter inside the query?

Answer (score 9):

You can externalize de `value`, which is the query itself. Inside the `src/main/resources`, create a folder called `META-INF`. Inside it, create a file called `jpa-named-queries.properties`.

Suppose your entity is called `Customer` and the table is `TBL_CUSTOMER`.

When you keep the query inside the code, on your repository, you have the code you wrote. You can externalize it this way:

CustomerRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true) 
    public List<String> findNameNative();

}
```

jpa-named-queries.properties

```
Customer.findNameNative=\
SELECT C.NAME \
FROM TBL_CUSTOMER C \
WHERE CONDITIONS
```

Names must match and you must use \ for line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Under resources create META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties. In this file define your queries this way:
MyEntity.fetchEntityBySomething=select name from Customer

I have not tried native queries however, usual queries would work this way.

However, check this out: https://github.com/gasparbarancelli/spring-native-query

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But this is not workimg. I tried with the same name and also tried jpa-naned-native-query.properies. But didn't work. Any additional configuration i need to put?

Comment: Does the externalization work if it is not a native query?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/gasparbarancelli/spring-native-query

Answer (score 0):

I think DarkKnight's solution is the best, set entity mappings with xml can take advantage of IDE to have highlight and indentation.

But if you are using spring boot, there will be an optimization.

There is a related spring boot property for it: `spring.jpa.mapping-resources`, you can set entity mappings path into this property. And this property can be an array, you can set more than one value into it.